# Converting Ant javadoc to Maven

Tags: maven, ant, javadoc

I'm converting my ant project to maven and want to add javadocs as well. I've added maven-javadoc-plugin, but I can't find anywere the whole list of its params :(.

My ant's javadoc was configured this way:

```
<javadoc access="public"
 author="true"
 classpath="${junit_jar}"
 destdir="../doc"
 doctitle="TarsosDSP API ${version}-${DSTAMP}"
 nodeprecated="false"
 nodeprecatedlist="false"
 noindex="false"
 nonavbar="false"
 notree="false"
 packagenames="a.lot.of.packages"
 source="1.6"
 sourcepath="../src"
 splitindex="true"
 use="true"
 version="true" />
```

How to produce the same config to maven?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [maven-javadoc-plugin configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html#Javadoc_Configuration)?

> The Javadoc Plugin supports a large number of configuration parameters. Each configuration parameter turns into a tag name.
>
> Please refer to the [Javadoc Plugin Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) for a listing of these parameters. Most of these parameters are passed directly to the Javadoc tool itself.

In other words, add the `<configuration>` tag to the `<plugin>` element (in either the `<build>` or the `<reporting>`section:

```
    <configuration>
      <show>public</show>
      <author>true</author>
      <!-- more configuration here -->
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, but I can't find a page with a _complete_ list of maven javadoc configuration properties

Comment: Agreeably, the documentation only states "most of these parameters", but the link in the documentation to the [Javadoc Plugin Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html) is extensive. I'm afraid I cannot give you a better answer, but you can ask them directly by posting to the [users list](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/mail-lists.html).